# Android: Activity freezes while running code that takes a while to complete

Tags: android, json, runnable

The app I am working on takes JSONs from a server and has to interpret them. I have around 6-7 JSONs that are requested.

As such, this is bound to take some time.

This code runs whenever the user types in information to an EditText and clicks a button. After the search button is clicked, the app freezes and will not do anything until all the data is loaded.

I tried having the code like this:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(summonerNameET.getWindowToken(), 0);
            final CollectUserData c = new CollectUserData();
            c.setRegion(region);
            c.setSummonerName(summonerNameET.getText().toString());

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        c.setUpTheJSONs();
                        updateUI(c);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            r.run();


        }
    });
```

But it still freezes. Here is the code for setUpTheJSON();

```
public void setUpTheJSONs() throws IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException {
    jsonSummonerInfo = getJsonSummonerInfo();
    if(canIContinue()) {
        jsonSummonerStats = getJsonSummaryStats();
        //jsonSummonerRankedStats = getJsonRankedStats();
        jsonSummonerMatchHistory = getJsonMatchHistory();
        jsonSummonerLeagueInfo = getJsonSummonerLeagueInfo();
        jsonSummonerRecentGames = getJsonSummonerRecentGames();
    }
}
```

And here is the code for unpdateUI(c);

```
public void updateUI(CollectUserData c) {
    if (c.canIContinue()) {
        String league = "";
        try {
            league = c.getMundaneCurrentLeague();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setLeague(tierIV, league);
        try {
            summonerNameTV.setText(c.getSummonerName());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            tierTV.setText(c.getTier());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            leaguePointsTV.setText(c.getLeaguePoints() + "");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            winsTV.setText("W: " + c.getWins());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        slashTV.setText("/");
        try {
            lossesTV.setText("L: " + c.getLosses());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            lastSeasonRankTV.setText("Season 4: " + c.getRankOfLastSeason());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameModeGameOneTV.setText(c.getGameType(1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneChampion.setBackground(c.getChampionPicturePlayed(1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneKillsTV.setText(c.getKills(1) + "");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gameOneSlashOneTV.setText(" / ");
        try {
            gameOneDeathsTV.setText(c.getDeaths(1) + "");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gameOneSlashTwoTV.setText(" / ");
        try {
            gameOneAssistsTV.setText(c.getAssists(1) + "");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneGoldTV.setText(c.getGold(1) + " K");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneCSTV.setText(" " + c.getMinionsKilled(1) + " CS");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean gameOneWon = true;
        try {
            gameOneWon = c.isGameWon(1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (gameOneWon) {
            gameOneTitleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d604c429"));
            gameOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4600FF06"));
        }
        if (!gameOneWon) {
            gameOneTitleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ff0100"));
            gameOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4fff0100"));
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemOneIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 0, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemTwoIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 1, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemThreeIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 2, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemFourIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 3, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemFiveIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 4, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            gameOneItemSixIV.setBackground(c.getItemFromMatchHistory(1, 5, getResources()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Drawable[] tempDrawable = null;
        try {
            tempDrawable = c.getTeamPlayerChampionIcon(1, 100);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (tempDrawable != null) {
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerOne.setBackground(tempDrawable[0]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerTwo.setBackground(tempDrawable[1]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerThree.setBackground(tempDrawable[2]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerFour.setBackground(tempDrawable[3]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerFive.setBackground(tempDrawable[4]);
        }
        Drawable[] tempDrawable2 = null;
        try {
            tempDrawable2 = c.getTeamPlayerChampionIcon(1, 200);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (tempDrawable != null) {
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerOne.setBackground(tempDrawable2[0]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerTwo.setBackground(tempDrawable2[1]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerThree.setBackground(tempDrawable2[2]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerFour.setBackground(tempDrawable2[3]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerFive.setBackground(tempDrawable2[4]);
        }
        String[] tempString = null;
        try {
            tempString = c.getTeamPlayerName(1, 100);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (tempString != null) {
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerOneName.setText(tempString[0]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerTwoName.setText(tempString[1]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerThreeName.setText(tempString[2]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerFourName.setText(tempString[3]);
            gameOneTeamOnePlayerFiveName.setText(tempString[4]);
        }
        String[] tempString2 = null;
        try {
            tempString2 = c.getTeamPlayerName(1, 200);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (tempString2 != null) {
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerOneName.setText(tempString2[0]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerTwoName.setText(tempString2[1]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerThreeName.setText(tempString2[2]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerFourName.setText(tempString2[3]);
            gameOneTeamTwoPlayerFiveName.setText(tempString2[4]);
        }

    }

}
```

Anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks ☺

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce multi threading. The r.run() command needs to be started by another thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are running the **Runnable** in the UI Thread and this is why you are getting your **UI blocked** until it finished. 

Try something like this:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(summonerNameET.getWindowToken(), 0);
        final CollectUserData c = new CollectUserData();
        c.setRegion(region);
        c.setSummonerName(summonerNameET.getText().toString());

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        c.setUpTheJSONs();
                        updateUI(c);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your downloading files in a separate thread. Use AsyncTask or Java Thread. Just simply.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      //Show progress dialog, if u want
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     //Do all your processing here! 

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      //Return some result to UI
    }
  }
```